# CMake path for python3 libraries doesn't change (windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-modules

Using Windows 10:
I'm trying to change the PYTHON3_LIBRARY path to the anaconda3 path *(C:/Users/Student/anaconda3/libs/python38.lib)* I have set in the value.
After I press configure I still get the normal python installation path as the result in the Python3: Libraries: *C:/Users/Student/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/libs/python38.lib (ver 3.8.8)*.
All the other pathes have the correct anaconda3 path, just not this one.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?
[image: Image of CMake, problem is marked]

I already uninstalled the python version from the wrong path and made sure the path does not exist any more, it still didn't change.
Also tried it with anaconda with python 3.9, didn't changed a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Anaconda3 multiple times, it worked.
I also always checked that it was added to the PATH variables.